# Parse Promises, destroyAll(); not working?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

The second line in the code below is not executing during a Cloud Job, why might this be the case? The prior line runs fine.

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll(apples).then(function() {
  return Parse.Object.destroyAll(pears); //Destroy all pear objects.
}, function(error) {
  status.error("Failed to destroy all apples/pears.");
});

status.success("Successfully deleted " + results.length + " pears.");
```

Comment: Does the function(error) line execute? If the second one fails, the function should not work. Add `.catch(function(error) {console.log(error)}` to see your exactly error if any at all.

Comment: There is no error, the function continues and succeeds. status.error(..) would set the job to failed if it executed, so no clue why it isn't doing that

Comment: So you are running the destroyAll statement twice... You destroyAll then destroyAll. Why are you running this twice?

Comment: Because the pear objects in my database need to be deleted. They are different from the apple objects, but the apple objects point to them. They occur in the success callback of a query.find();

Comment: Add the `.then` and `status.success` on the `destroyAll(pears)` just as you have on the `destroyAll(apples)` and see what comes out of it. Some message must be coming out of this.

Comment: @BrianGerhards Thank you for the assistance, the solution below solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `status.success` is run synchronously before the destroyAll(pears) would even get a chance to run

try it this way

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll(apples).then(function() {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(pears); //Destroy all pear objects.
}).then(function() {
    status.success("Successfully deleted " + results.length + " pears.");
}, function(error) {
    status.error("Failed to destroy all apples/pears.");
});
```